# Ajax Call Delayed by SetInterval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have this ajax call which is a recurring call every 10 seconds. This works perfectly However, the Visits counter only updates 10 seconds after page load. Until then, it is empty. If I set it to 60 seconds, which is more practical I think, then the area is BLANK for 60 seconds and only then the data appears.

How can I modify this to get the value of Visits immediately on page load and then continuously refresh it every 10 seconds?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Visits = 0; 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#counter").flipCounter(); 
  setInterval("ajaxd()",10000);
});

function ajaxd(){   // this function is called only after 10 seconds after page load
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache:false,
  url: "getVisits.asp?dx=1,   // returns a number
  dataType: "text",
  data: "",
  success: function(data){
       Visits= parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);
  }
});
/// update value in <div>
```

```
$("#counter").flipCounter(
"startAnimation", // scroll counter from the current number to the specified number
{
start_number: 0, // the number we want to scroll from
end_number: Visits, // the number we want the counter to scroll to
numIntegralDigits: Visits.length-3, // number of places left of the decimal point to maintain
numFractionalDigits:2, // number of places right of the decimal point to maintain
easing: jQuery.easing.easeOutCubic, // this easing function to apply to the scroll.
duration: 3000 // number of ms animation should take to complete
});   
}
```

FINALLY, this part where the counter is to appear:

```
<div id="counter" class="bb_box">
<input type="hidden" name="counter-value" value="00.00"/>
</div>
```

Comment: never ever use string param in setInterval, since it a special form of eval actually.

Comment: I am open to any other solution that will do this

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#counter").flipCounter(); 
  setInterval("ajaxd()",10000);
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#counter").flipCounter(); 
  setInterval(ajaxd,10000);
  ajaxd();  // add this to call ajax once immediately
});
```

And move this code block to the end of script block, to avoid calling undefined functions.

**UPDATE**
you might try like this:

```
var Visits = 0; 

function ajaxd(){   
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache:false,
  url: "getVisits.asp?dx=1,   // returns a number
  dataType: "text",
  data: "",
  success: function(data){
       Visits= parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);
       $("#counter").flipCounter("setNumber", Visits);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#counter").flipCounter(); 
  setInterval(ajaxd, 10000);
  ajaxd();
});
```

Comment: Hi Goran, that did not work. Still wont do anything for 10 seconds.

Comment: Is there any error in console? Can you try type 'ajaxd()' into js console when page loads? Can you add a console.log("ajaxd called") line to your ajaxd function to check if it was called?

Comment: try to move whole function before $(document).ready block, it may be undefined at moment you are calling it and makes js error

Comment: Its strange. The ajaxd() function does execute immediately on page load but on the first run it always sets the value of Visits = 0. I think there is some jump in the order of execution of the various steps. It seems to always go to   $("#counter").flipCounter(); without waiting for the value to be returned by the query. To put this in perspective, I am executing the whole script on a single machine so the ajax query should return any values almost instantly.

Comment: Aaah flipCounter reads Visit and sets value? You need to move that AFTER your ajax call returns, so it needs to be in success function. I will now update my answer according to that assumption.

Comment: Nevermind, I found flipCounter plugin, will check how it works now

Comment: do you have any feedback? I have tried to place the ajaxd() call in various locations but it still will not trigger the counter on the first load of the page. Sorry for a late response. Thanks for all the earlier feedback.

Comment: I updated my answer when I saw how counter works. Check my update. Do you set counter value by using "setNumber" like in my example?

Comment: Hi Goran, posted the full code as it is. The edits you posted did not seems to work, probably because I did not understand the "setCounter" call. Maybe the full code will help. Thanks.

Comment: Just try changing `Visits= parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);` to `$("#counter").flipCounter("setNumber", parseFloat(data).toFixed(2));` It should work, it may give you an error if you call it before counter is initialized.

Comment: And alternatively, if your code is working as it is, just move $(document).ready part to the end of script and add ajaxd() before closing parentheses (like in my answer). If that gives you error, check what it says in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see ajaxd() is after the function)

```
setInterval(function() {
ajaxd();

}, 10000);

function ajaxd(){   // this function is called only after 10 seconds after page load
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache:false,
  url: "getVisits.asp?dx=1,   // returns a number
  dataType: "text",
  data: "",
  success: function(data){
       Visits= parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);
  }

 ajaxd();
```

Comment: I am using some similar codes to populate graphs and refresh in 1 minute, the graph is loaded with data from server at the time of page load and refreshed in every minute.